# PagingScrollTable - disappear backround image with cell when selected

Tags: gwt

Anyone know how I can do to when I select the row does not disappear me the background image of the cell that I inserted?

Thanks Vert Much!
Jero

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler to the cell, or override its onBrowserEvent and hide the background there.

Provide some code, then we can answer more specifically.